PandasDataset.from_long_dataframe Error: AssertionError when using gluonts, static_feature_columns and use_feat_static_cat=True
I'm struggling with setting up PandasDataset.from_long_dataframe. The error code is not specified clearly, and I can't fix it as I'm not sure where the problem is. I suspect there's an issue with static_feature_columns=static_cat_columns and use_feat_static_cat=True, but I can't recognize the relation between them.
Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mxnet as mx
from gluonts.dataset.pandas import PandasDataset
from gluonts.mx import DeepAREstimator, Trainer
from gluonts.evaluation import make_evaluation_predictions
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error

# Set date range
final_custom_dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(final_custom_dataset['date'])
start_date = '2016-01-01'
end_date = '2017-08-15'
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

def generate_single_ts_with_features(final_custom_dataset, item_id, date_range) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ts = final_custom_dataset[final_custom_dataset['new_id'] == item_id].copy()
    ts.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    ts = ts.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)
    ts['new_id'] = item_id
    ts['date'] = ts.index
    return ts 

# Generate multiple time series data
multiple_ts = {
    item_id: generate_single_ts_with_features(final_custom_dataset, item_id, date_range)
    for item_id in ['25_AUTOMOTIVE', '26_AUTOMOTIVE']  # final_custom_dataset['new_id'].unique()
}

# Combine multiple time series data into a single DataFrame
multiple_ts_long = pd.concat(multiple_ts.values(), axis=0)

# Ensure all required columns are present
required_columns = [
    "onpromotion", "onpromotion_lag1", "day_of_week_Friday", "day_of_week_Monday", 
    "day_of_week_Saturday", "day_of_week_Sunday", "day_of_week_Thursday", 
    "day_of_week_Tuesday", "day_of_week_Wednesday", "sales", "new_id", "date"
]
for col in required_columns:
    if col not in multiple_ts_long.columns:
        multiple_ts_long[col] = 0

# Define dynamic_real_columns and static_cat_columns
dynamic_real_columns = [
    "onpromotion", "onpromotion_lag1"
]

static_cat_columns = [
    "day_of_week_Friday", "day_of_week_Monday", 
    "day_of_week_Saturday", "day_of_week_Sunday", 
    "day_of_week_Thursday", "day_of_week_Tuesday", 
    "day_of_week_Wednesday"
]


# Create PandasDataset for long dataset
multiple_ts_long_dataset = PandasDataset.from_long_dataframe(
    multiple_ts_long,
    item_id="new_id",
    timestamp="date",
    feat_dynamic_real=dynamic_real_columns,
    static_feature_columns=static_cat_columns,
    target="sales",
    freq='D'  # freq setting added
)

# Set GPU context
ctx = mx.gpu() if mx.context.num_gpus() > 0 else mx.cpu()

# Compute cardinality and embedding_dimension
cardinality = [2 for _ in static_cat_columns]
embedding_dimension = [min(50, (cat + 1) // 2) for cat in cardinality]

# Train the model
estimator = DeepAREstimator(
    freq="D",
    prediction_length=16,
    use_feat_dynamic_real=True,
    use_feat_static_cat=True,
    cardinality=cardinality,
    embedding_dimension=embedding_dimension,
    trainer=Trainer(epochs=1, ctx=ctx)
)

predictor = estimator.train(multiple_ts_long_dataset)

# Make predictions
forecast_it, ts_it = make_evaluation_predictions(
    dataset=multiple_ts_long_dataset, 
    predictor=predictor, 
    num_samples=100
)

# Retrieve forecasts and actual values
forecasts = list(forecast_it)
tss = list(ts_it)

# Calculate MSLE
msle_values = []
for ts, forecast in zip(tss, forecasts):
    actual = ts[-forecast.prediction_length:].values
    predicted = forecast.mean
    msle = mean_squared_log_error(actual, predicted)
    msle_values.append(msle)
    print(f"MSLE: {msle}")

# Print average MSLE
average_msle = np.mean(msle_values)
print(f"Average MSLE: {average_msle}")


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-18bccb777b58> in <cell line: 56>()
     54 
     55 # Create PandasDataset for long dataset
---> 56 multiple_ts_long_dataset = PandasDataset.from_long_dataframe(
     57     multiple_ts_long,
     58     item_id="new_id",

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gluonts/dataset/pandas.py in from_long_dataframe(cls, dataframe, item_id, timestamp, static_feature_columns, static_features, **kwargs)
    299                 .set_index(item_id)
    300             )
--> 301             assert len(other_static_features) == len(
    302                 dataframe[item_id].unique()
    303             )

AssertionError: 

I suspect there's an issue with how I'm using static_feature_columns=static_cat_columns and use_feat_static_cat=True. Could anyone help me understand the relationship between these parameters and how to resolve this error?
